# Solved: Qml Application (Qt6) cannot be run on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, qml, qt6

**Update:**

Problem solved: I initially made the error to use `qt_generate_deploy_app_script` and later changed it to `qt_generate_deploy_qml_app_script` but I did not recreate the build folder. Additionally I did not call `qt_finalize_target`. These things sorted out everything works flawlessly.

---

Im am setting up an application that should be built with Qml and Qt6. I set up the build with CMake and use `qt_generate_deploy_qml_app_script` to bundle the dlls on Windows.
The build process works well and I can also generate a NSIS installer package. However, whenever I try to run the application, I get errors that something cannot be found. First I got the error that the module `QtQuick.Controls` is not available, so I removed that. Now I get the error `MenuBar is not a type`. The application starts without errors on linux but it won't run on Windows.

When I create the package, I get some folder `_CPack_Packages/win64/NSIS/myapp-1.0.0-win64`. There the entire folder structure of the to be installed application can be found:

```
$ tree build/_CPack_Packages/win64/NSIS/myapp-1.0.0-win64
build/_CPack_Packages/win64/NSIS/myapp-1.0.0-win64
|-- bin
|   |-- D3Dcompiler_47.dll
|   |-- Qt6Core.dll
|   |-- Qt6Gui.dll
|   |-- Qt6Network.dll
|   |-- Qt6OpenGL.dll
|   |-- Qt6Pdf.dll
|   |-- Qt6Qml.dll
|   |-- Qt6QmlModels.dll
|   |-- Qt6QmlModelsd.dll
|   |-- Qt6QmlWorkerScript.dll
|   |-- Qt6QmlWorkerScriptd.dll
|   |-- Qt6Quick.dll
|   |-- Qt6QuickControls2.dll
|   |-- Qt6QuickControls2Impl.dll
|   |-- Qt6QuickControls2Impld.dll
|   |-- Qt6QuickDialogs2.dll
|   |-- Qt6QuickDialogs2QuickImpl.dll
|   |-- Qt6QuickDialogs2QuickImpld.dll
|   |-- Qt6QuickDialogs2Utils.dll
|   |-- Qt6QuickDialogs2Utilsd.dll
|   |-- Qt6QuickDialogs2d.dll
|   |-- Qt6QuickTemplates2.dll
|   |-- Qt6QuickTemplates2d.dll
|   |-- Qt6Svg.dll
|   |-- concrt140.dll
|   |-- myapp.exe
|   |-- msvcp140.dll
|   |-- msvcp140_1.dll
|   |-- msvcp140_2.dll
|   |-- msvcp140_atomic_wait.dll
|   |-- msvcp140_codecvt_ids.dll
|   |-- opengl32sw.dll
|   |-- qt.conf
|   |-- vcruntime140.dll
|   `-- vcruntime140_1.dll
|-- plugins
|   |-- iconengines
|   |   `-- qsvgicon.dll
|   |-- imageformats
|   |   |-- qgif.dll
|   |   |-- qicns.dll
|   |   |-- qico.dll
|   |   |-- qjpeg.dll
|   |   |-- qpdf.dll
|   |   |-- qsvg.dll
|   |   |-- qtga.dll
|   |   |-- qtiff.dll
|   |   |-- qwbmp.dll
|   |   `-- qwebp.dll
|   |-- networkinformation
|   |   `-- qnetworklistmanager.dll
|   |-- platforminputcontexts
|   |   `-- qtvirtualkeyboardplugin.dll
|   |-- platforms
|   |   `-- qwindows.dll
|   |-- qmltooling
|   |   |-- qmldbg_debugger.dll
|   |   |-- qmldbg_inspector.dll
|   |   |-- qmldbg_local.dll
|   |   |-- qmldbg_messages.dll
|   |   |-- qmldbg_native.dll
|   |   |-- qmldbg_nativedebugger.dll
|   |   |-- qmldbg_preview.dll
|   |   |-- qmldbg_profiler.dll
|   |   |-- qmldbg_quick3dprofiler.dll
|   |   |-- qmldbg_quickprofiler.dll
|   |   |-- qmldbg_server.dll
|   |   `-- qmldbg_tcp.dll
|   `-- tls
|       |-- qcertonlybackend.dll
|       |-- qopensslbackend.dll
|       `-- qschannelbackend.dll
|-- qml
|   |-- QtQml
|   |   |-- Models
|   |   |   |-- modelsplugin.dll
|   |   |   |-- modelsplugind.dll
|   |   |   `-- qmldir
|   |   |-- WorkerScript
|   |   |   |-- qmldir
|   |   |   |-- workerscriptplugin.dll
|   |   |   `-- workerscriptplugind.dll
|   |   |-- qmldir
|   |   |-- qmlplugin.dll
|   |   `-- qmlplugind.dll
|   `-- QtQuick
|       |-- Dialogs
|       |   |-- qmldir
|       |   |-- qtquickdialogsplugin.dll
|       |   `-- qtquickdialogsplugind.dll
|       |-- qmldir
|       |-- qtquick2plugin.dll
|       `-- qtquick2plugind.dll
|-- share
|   `-- pixmaps
|       `-- myappicon.png
`-- translations
    |-- qt_ar.qm
    |-- qt_bg.qm
    |-- qt_ca.qm
    |-- qt_cs.qm
    |-- qt_da.qm
    |-- qt_de.qm
    |-- qt_en.qm
    |-- qt_es.qm
    |-- qt_fa.qm
    |-- qt_fi.qm
    |-- qt_fr.qm
    |-- qt_gd.qm
    |-- qt_he.qm
    |-- qt_hr.qm
    |-- qt_hu.qm
    |-- qt_it.qm
    |-- qt_ja.qm
    |-- qt_ko.qm
    |-- qt_lv.qm
    |-- qt_nl.qm
    |-- qt_nn.qm
    |-- qt_pl.qm
    |-- qt_pt_BR.qm
    |-- qt_ru.qm
    |-- qt_sk.qm
    |-- qt_tr.qm
    |-- qt_uk.qm
    |-- qt_zh_CN.qm
    `-- qt_zh_TW.qm

18 directories, 109 files
```

It seems that everything is there, nevertheless I get:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/qml/Main:30:13 MenuItem is no type
```

When I start it a second time, I get `ApplicationWindow is no type` or `Action is no type`.

The qml file is very basic:

```
import QtQuick

import QtQuick.Dialogs

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 620
    height: 480


    FileDialog {
        id: openFileDialog
        fileMode: FileDialog.OpenFile
        title: qsTr ("Please chose the database to use.")
        onAccepted: {
            console.log ("You chose " + openFileDialog.selectedFile)
        }
    }

    Action {
        id: openFileAction
        text: qsTr ("&Open")
        onTriggered: openFileDialog.open()
    }

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr ("&File")
            MenuItem { action: openFileAction }
        }
    }

    SplitView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal

        handle: Rectangle {
            id: handleDelegate
            implicitWidth: 4
            implicitHeight: 4
            color: "#cccccc"

        }

        Rectangle {
            id: treeBox
            SplitView.minimumWidth: 200
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: mainBox
            width: 320
            SplitView.fillWidth: true

        }
    }
}
```

This works flawlessly on linux but I just cannot get that to work on Windows, even though a ton of dlls is deployed. What am I missing?

I tried to remove modules, like the `QtQuick.Controls` since I got the error that this is missing (even though the dll is there). I searched for any issue concerning the deployment script, there is none that affects me. I double-checked the Qt docs but I could not see anything I do different.

**UPDATE:**

`QtQuick.Controls` is needed since all those Types come from there. Therefore I need to `import QtQuick.Controls` but exactly this fails with

```
 Module "QtQuick.Controls" Plugin "qtquickcontrols2plugin" could not be found
```

I guess this means that I should have such a plugin within `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/qml/QtQml`?... But why do others like `qml/QtQuick/Dialogs` exist but `Controls` not? I thought this is handled by `qt_generate_deploy_qml_app_script`, I explicitly link to `Qt6::QuickControls2`. This installs the corresponding library but not the qml Modules?

Comment: If you have found a solution for your problem, then write an **answer** (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). On Stack Overflow the question post should never contain a solution.